# three.js, clothing and shape keys

Tags: three.js, blender

How can I dress a human body?. I have imported the body model and t-shirt in two separated meshes. The human body includes shape keys.

But when I modify the morphTargetInfluences key of the body, the t-shirt doesn't fit in the new body shape.
How can I make the T-shirt fits when the key change the value?, How can I do that using three.js?

I'm using the version 1.4.0 of the Three.js exporter (three.js r71) and Blender 2.75a

[image]

Comment: you need to use cloth simulation along with collision detection. http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_animation_cloth.html

Comment: I am trying to do same thing. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am trying achieve same thing, would you mind in sharing the git repo thanks

Comment: Create shape keys for the shirt that fits the body and then connect the relationship in your UI. Or you can also do a collision detection stuff

Answer (score 0):

The point is, your morph targets are only present in your character model and won't magically fit the cloth unfortunately. Apply the morph to the cloth too in your editing tool and morph both equally, this would work without extra effort.

I'm actually also working on a solution for wearable cloth, i'll give shared vertex buffers a try where the vertices "connects" to the vertices of the domain model with a relative offset, so you would just have to take care about assigning the cloth once, instead applying and exporting whole morph target sets at all.

The downside would be, your vertices has to stay the same, once you modify the mesh, you'd have to export all related cloth again. This can be basically solved by a automated process, like one which searches for nearest vertices, but cloth is usually extruded from the base mesh to perfectly "fit" without intersections, so this isn't really a surprising thing.