# Constraining Cloth in Three.JS

Tags: javascript, three.js

(This is probably a noob question.) So I'm trying to "fit" a cloth material to a character model in Three.JS. What is the best way to do this? Do you model a complete, closed garment and import it as cloth geometry, then place it on the model and just apply some sort of physics library? Do you define a set of constraints where the cloth is "pinned" to the model, and let the rest loose?

To get some direction I examined the code behind [Three's cloth example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_animation_cloth). However, the only part I could see that related to constraining the cloth mesh involved "pin" variables that, as far as I could tell, weren't implemented anywhere outside of their assignment functions:

```js
/* testing cloth simulation */

var pinsFormation = [];
var pins = [6];

pinsFormation.push(pins);

pins = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
pinsFormation.push(pins);

pins = [0];
pinsFormation.push(pins);

pins = []; // cut the rope ;)
pinsFormation.push(pins);

pins = [0, cloth.w]; // classic 2 pins
pinsFormation.push(pins);

pins = pinsFormation[1];


function togglePins() {

  pins = pinsFormation[~~(Math.random() * pinsFormation.length)];

}
```

Does anyone have experience with this sort of thing?

I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31667615/three-js-clothing-and-shape-keys), which was answered only rudimentarily ("collision detection") and referred to the example code I couldn't figure out.

I'm new to this, so sorry if this has an obvious answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

honestly, I just wouldn't bother trying to simulate the cloth onto the shirt, you'll end up doing raytracing for ever vertex of the cloth and that means it'll run about 5fps on even a fast machine (or you'll have only 20 vertices in the cloth). I would just put clothing on the model in whatever 3d program you're using and then deform the model (with clothes on).

[You can see here what I mean.](https://clara.io/view/00610b66-62b1-431e-a8de-234f396be98e) They didn't simulate cloth on the player, they just made a player model that included clothes and then did bone deformations for the animation and it looks great.

If you are a beginner, (even if you're an expert) then this is where I would start, because getting dynamic cloth interactions with complicated meshes is a really tough place to start and I don't see the advantages unless it's purely for simulation purposes and real-time performance isn't that important to you.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm thinking now of deforming the clothing model onto the player model with cloth physics in Blender (via python, though the documentation for doing it as a script as opposed to with a GUI is lacking).

Comment: yeah, maybe there's a way to do that, and then just capture a state and use that, so that you get naturalistic, dynamic cloth laying on the model without needing to do your own modelling of folds and creases and whatnot